# Javascript: What happens to objects that don't have a name?

Tags: javascript

If I do the following (in the global scope):

```
var myObject = {name: "Bob"};
```

I have a way to point to that object in memory (i.e. the string identifier "myObject)". I can open the console and type: `myObject.name` and the console will respond with:

```
"Bob"
```

Now, if I just type:

```
{name: "Jane"};
```

I'm creating that object somewhere and I'm guessing it goes on living in some scope. Is there any way I can find it? Does it exists under `window` somewhere in some generic store?

Edit: Some people are saying it will just get garbage collected.

So how about this example:

```
var MyObject = function(){
    $("button").click(this.alert);
}

MyObject.prototype.alert = function(){
    alert("I heard that!")
}

new MyObject();
```

It can't be garbage collected because its callback is bound to a DOM event. Where does the resulting object live and can it be accessed?

Comment: Nope. The object is created and garbage collected. Just like those `"use strict";` string. I thing some JS engines may even avoid to create

Comment: Someone else questioned this but deleted their comment. Is your first example definitely even defining the object that you think or is it just a block, a label and a string?

Comment: I've updated my answer, to expand a bit on your update (about binding event handlers in a constructor, which, might I add, generally isn't the best idea(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is *no*, the object isn't kept alive in memory somewhere you can't reach. Bit life is live: the truth is a bit more complicated, but not by much, if you grasp the basics.

*Update:*
In response to your update: you're right, in a way. The callback is a reference to `MyObject.prototype.alert`, which you accessed using `this.alert`, but that function object is being referenced by a constructors prototype, and can't be GC'ed anyway. The *instance* itself is not involved in the `alert` function itself, so it can be GC'ed safely.

Think of it like this:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.alert = 0x000123;//some memory address
   ||
   \/
0x000123 = [object Function];
```

The function object itself isn't directly attached to anything, it floats there in memory, and is being referenced by the prototype. When you create an instance:

```
new MyConstructor().alert;
```

Is resolved as follows:

```
[new MyConstructor instance] allocated at e.g 0x000321
   ||
   \\
    \=>[alert] check for alert @instance -> not found
          \\
           \=> check prototype, yield 0x000123 <-- memory address, return this value
```

So upon executing the statement:

```
 $("button").click(this.alert);
```

`this.alert` is an expression that is resolved to `0x000123`. In other words, jQ's `click` method (function object) only receives the memory address of the `alert` function object. The instance, or indeed the constructor isn't involved at all. That's why `this`, or the call-context, can change depending on how and where a function is invoked. [see here for more on ad-hoc context determination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346206/targeting-this-within-nested-for-each-loops-in-jquery/16346298#16346298)

I'll even do you one better:

```
/*assume your code is here*/
new MyConstructor().alert = function(){ alert('I am deaf');};
MyConstructor.prototype.alert = 'foo';
$('#button').click();
```

Guess what, the click event alert *"I heard that"* all the same, the *prototype* isn't even involved, let alone the instance.
If `MyConstructor` were to go out of scope, the `click` event will still work fine, because the GC still sees a reference to the alert function object that isn't out of scope yet. everything else is available for GC'ing, though...

---

The JS garbage collector (GC) is a flag-and-swipe GC. When the JS engine encounters your statement, it *does* allocate the memory required to store your object. When the next statement is reached, that object will probably still be in memory.
Every now and then, the GC X-checks all the objects it sees in memory, and tries to locate all references to that object that are still accessible. When it comes across the object literal that was just created in that statement, but no reference to was assigned, the object is flagged for garbage collection.
The next time the GC gets about its business of swiping flagged object, that object will be removed from memory.

Of course, this isn't entirely true for *all* engines. suppose your statement was written in an IIFE, that returned a function:

```
var foo = function()
{
    {name: 'bar'};
    return function()
    {
        return 'foobar';
    };
}());
```

Some engines just keep the entire scope of the IIFE in memory, and only deallocate the memory for that scope when the *return value* of the IIFE goes out of scope (is flagged for GC). Other engines, like V8 last time I checked, will in fact flag those objects/vars of the outer scope that aren't referenced by its return value.
Though, come to think about it, it might not apply to this case, because the GC might even kick in even before the IIFE returns... But on the whole, that's just nit-picking.

There's also the question of logical OR's to consider:

```
var name = (mayNotExist || {name:'default'}).name;
```

In this case, if `mayNotExist` *does* exist, the object literal will never even be created, thanks to JS's short-circuit evaluation of expressions.

A couple of links on the matter:

- [Objects and functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500101/objects-and-functions-in-javascript/13500475#13500475)
- [javascript - How to make this code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472577/javascript-how-to-make-this-code-work/#16472719)
- [What makes my.class.js so fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213074/what-makes-my-class-js-so-fast/14336037#14336037)
- [Properties of Javascript function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174187/properties-of-javascript-function-objects/15174505#15174505)

Comment: Thanks for the very complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

If there is no reference pointing to this object (that is you didn't assign it to any variable or to the value of any property), then there is no way to access it and in fact it's no living as the garbage collector can reclaim this memory immediately.

Comment: I like to think it has escaped and is living on the lamb.

Comment: @Yatrix I think it's 'on the lam' but 'living on the lamb' sounds tastier!

Comment: @MattHarrison Hehe. I've never been on the lam, but if I ever am, I hope I have lamb to take with me.