# Memory Allocation in Javascript for duplicate object

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

Let's assume that ajax response is 5mb which i get from an ajax call.

```
function(ajaxresponse){

    var ajaxdata = ajaxresponse;

    then

    var ajaxdata2 = ajaxresponse; //as per the reply below this is a reference and hence new memory isn't allocated

    var ajaxdata3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ajaxresponse));

}
```

Would 15mb, 10 mb or 5mb be utilized?

Comment: 5 MB - you are duplicating the reference - not the data

Comment: I believe you are just creating pointers to the original 'ajaxresponse' parameter. So there is no new memory allocation. You can test this by changing something in ajaxdata2 - it should also have changed in ajaxdata and ajaxresponse

Comment: `ajaxdata2` is just a reference to the value in `ajaxdata`  No new value is created.

Comment: Wow that is something i didn't know !

Comment: Yeah sorry...this was the my original intent of asking the question... added a comment so the the replies are still relevent.

Comment: @ZendNoob ok I have edited it to ask about both duplicating reference and content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. JavaScript always passes/assigns by value, but an object's value is *never* really assigned to a variable. The way to think about objects and the memory management in JS is something like this:

All Objects (be it functions, object literals, arrays, prototypes...) reside somewhere in memory. These spaces in memory can either be referenced by a variable or not. But they stay *put* as it were. You can have any number of variables that are assigned *the address of this object*, but you can't copy the object itself, not directly anyway.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366276/javascript-what-happens-to-objects-that-dont-have-a-name/17366399#17366399) which contains a number of diagrams and some more details on how JS works, including links to even more info...

Just try:

```
var a = {foo: 'bar'},
b;
b = a;
console.log(b.foo);//bar
b.foo += ' appended through b reference';
console.log(a.foo);//bar appended through b reference
```

`a` and `b` reference *the same* object, no additional memory required... save for the minute bit of mem required to store the `b` variable.
What the *actual* value is of `a` or `b` in this example is something like `0XB16B00B6`. Or in C-speak, they actually behave as a dereferenced pointer.

---

In some cases, people *do* want to copy objects. Now this is quite hard to accomplish, owing to JS's design. If the object contains nothing but data, then the easiest way of doing this is:

```
var copiedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObject));
```

But if you're dealing with an object that also carries its own methods, then you're in a whole new world of trouble, and you'll have to do something like this:

```
//after doing:var copiedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someObject));
function copyFunctions(srcObj, targetObj)
{
    var prop;
    for (prop in srcObj)
    {
        if (srcObj[prop] instanceof Object)
        {
            if (srcObj[prop] instanceof Function)
            {
                targetObj[prop] = srcObj[prop];//this is a REFERENCE, still
                //OR, to ensure correct this binding!
                targetObj[prop] = (function(rebind, actualFunc)
                {
                    return function()
                    {
                        actualFunc.bind(this);
                        var returnVal = actualFunc.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
                        actualFunc.bind(rebind);
                    };
                }(srcObj, srcObj[prop]));
            }
            else
            {
                if (srcObj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                {//avoid copying prototypal methods
                    targetObj[prop] = copyFunctions(srcObj[prop], targetObj[prop] || {});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return targetObj;
}
```

Please note that this code is just off the top of my head, and is not tested in any way. It doesn't check for recursion, so it's not safe to use... but you get the gist of it, I hope.

Now, how could the code in your question *alter* the memory usage? Simple: `JSON.stringify` returns *a string constant*. This string has no binding to the original object any longer, so JS will allocate new memory to accomodate the memory for this string. Then, this string is being passed to `JSON.parse`. Again, a *new object* will be created, allocating memory for this object (that does not reference the original object) is required.
After assigning to `ajaxdata3`, the GC (GarbageCollector) kicks in. It'll find 2 references to a single object, so that object can't be GC'ed. It'll also register a second object, which is being referenced by the variable `ajaxdata3`, so that object, too, will remain in memory.
The return value of `JSON.stringify` is found, too, only this time, the GC sees that this string constant isn't being referenced anywhere, and so it flags that section of the memory. The next time the GC starts up, it'll check all *flagged* bits of memory and deallocate them (free them for usage).

Comment: Thanks that was an eyeopener !

Comment: I changed the code so that its no longer an reference. How would the memory allocation be affected ?

Comment: @ZendNoob: How did you change the code? `JSON.stringify`? because if it's an object, it'll always be a reference...

Comment: Yes I changed the code how will the memory be affected now ?

Comment: So ajaxdata3 would still be a reference not new content ?

Comment: @ZendNoob: Nope, `ajaxdata3` will not reference the original object, because the object it references was created from a string constant. In terms of mem-usage you'll use 5MB, then a spike of 10Mb + ~2Mb for string (`JSON.parse` return value), to then return to 10Mb of RAM usage

Comment: Much less worrying.